# MISRA C rule 12.2

Tags: c, misra

I am new to MISRA rules concepts. I have a rule 12.2 warning saying

> The value of an expression shall be the same under any order of
>   evaluation that the standard permits (MISRA C 2004)

on the following C code:

```
PtToStack->Entry[PtToStack->top] = e ;
```

where `PtToStack` is pointer to stack, `Entry` is array in the stack structure and `top` variable is a field of the stack structure. 
`e` has the same type of `Entry`.

Could any one help me to understand the warning?

Comment: Looks like an broken warning to me. Apparently MIRSA is a standard, not a program. What gives you the warning then?

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: Yes, it certainly looks like a buggy tool.

Comment: The warning seems wrong. A possible workaround: `index = PtToStack->top; PtToStack->Entry[index] = e;`.

Comment: Or see what it says about `(PtToStack->Entry)[PtToStack->top] = e;`

Comment: In a language with operator overloading, evaluation of the `->` or `[]` operator could, in principle, alter the value of `e` or of `PtToStack->top` or `PtToStack->Entry` in the course of evaluating the overall statement expression, which might justify a warning about that MISRA rule.  But C is not such a language.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right rule and the right line of the right file?

Comment: `PtToStack` is not `volatile`, is it?

Comment: Please name which tool you are using, so we can shame it publicly on the internet and prevent others from buying it. Why are you using an old MISRA standard btw, and not the current one?

Comment: Could you show the full definition/declaration of the PtToStack structure type and object, and the definition/declaration of e

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the struct is volatile and there are side effects, because they will be evaluated in a deterministic order here. The only thing that could be relevant is if this struct contains a C11 anonymous union or such, but then it won't be MISRA-compliant no matter, since MISRA-C:2004 requires C90.

Answer (score 1):

This rule from MISRA-C:2004 (older standard) is concerning the order of evaluation of operands, in expressions where the order is not specified. There are plenty of examples and education material regarding the issue, below rule 12.2.

In your expression, there are no issues with unspecified order of evaluation. Therefore, the warning is incorrectly generated by your tool. Your static analyser is bad, file a bug report with the tool vendor.